# slightly different scrolling needed after searching

Tags: iphone, uiview, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar below a header-view. This header is 64px hight. If the searchbar gets touched, the parent view will move 64px up — fine.

After finishing searching the parent view will only move down, as long there is still free space below it. And the top is out of the visible bounds.

But I want to move it back to the original position every time searching finished. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `UISerachDisplayDelegate`-method `-searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:`

like this:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] 
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```